# How to check the p values of parameters in OLS

Tags: python, statsmodels

When running a linear regression, like `y=a*x+b`, the summary gives me the p-values of whether the parameters equal to zero, what if I would like to see the p-value of whether the parameter `a` equals to 2 or something different from zero?

I expect the **OLS** summary gives me the p value of whether `a` is different from 2.

Comment: please give more details, and, perhaps, a code snippet with its output. Now it is not even clear what package you're using

Comment: Hi, I use statsmodels.regression.linear_model.OLS, after fit, I can get a summay table which contains the p values of paramaters, I just want to test whether one of the parameter is  different from a number(not 0).

Comment: I'm still not sure I understand your question, but why don't you use standard error for the estimated parameter to calculate p-value?

Comment: Hi, I could, but I wonder if there is a function that can help me with my issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The results classes have methods for hypothesis testing. Most of them are based on Wald test, that is we estimate the full model and test whether a restriction is consistent with the data.

http://www.statsmodels.org/devel/generated/statsmodels.regression.linear_model.RegressionResults.html

See for example `t_test` which is vectorized for simple hypothesis and produces a summary table similar to the one in the regression summary.
http://www.statsmodels.org/devel/generated/statsmodels.regression.linear_model.RegressionResults.t_test.html
which has this example

```
>>> results = ols(formula, dta).fit()
>>> hypotheses = 'GNPDEFL = GNP, UNEMP = 2, YEAR/1829 = 1'
>>> t_test = results.t_test(hypotheses)
```

There are several other methods available for hypothesis testing:
`wald_test` is for a single joint hypothesis.
`wald_test_terms` tests whether each term has all parameters equal to zero (e.g. for categorical regressors) and
`t_test_pairwise` computes the t_test for each pair of levels for a categorical regressors.

Comment: This works, thanks a lot. By the way, do you know how to convert this result to `summary_col` of `statsmodels.iolib.summary2`?

Comment: AFAIK that's not possible. `summary_col` has an `info_dict` keyword that can be applied to add individual rows, but I don't see an option to add additional parameters/effects including p-values or standard errors. enhancement request ?

Answer (score 0):

my comment explained:

Here is an example of the OLS result (data are artificial):

```
                            OLS Regression Results                            
==============================================================================
Dep. Variable:                      y   R-squared:                       0.161
Model:                            OLS   Adj. R-squared:                 -0.007
Method:                 Least Squares   F-statistic:                    0.9608
Date:                Mon, 08 Apr 2019   Prob (F-statistic):              0.372
Time:                        11:14:10   Log-Likelihood:                -10.854
No. Observations:                   7   AIC:                             25.71
Df Residuals:                       5   BIC:                             25.60
Df Model:                           1                                         
Covariance Type:            nonrobust                                         
==============================================================================
                 coef    std err          t      P>|t|      [0.025      0.975]
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
const          2.1429      1.141      1.879      0.119      -0.789       5.075
x1             0.2500      0.255      0.980      0.372      -0.406       0.906
==============================================================================
Omnibus:                          nan   Durbin-Watson:                   1.743
Prob(Omnibus):                    nan   Jarque-Bera (JB):                0.482
Skew:                           0.206   Prob(JB):                        0.786
Kurtosis:                       1.782   Cond. No.                         10.4
==============================================================================
```

So, for parameter x1 we have coefficient 0.25 with STD 0.255.

p-value of x1=1:

```
>>> from scipy.stats import norm
>>> 2*(1 - norm.cdf(abs(1-0.25), scale=0.255))                                                                                          
0.00326968201269362
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this works. However I would also like to have a table using `summary_col` like the 'table 2' here, [link](https://lectures.quantecon.org/py/ols.html), It would be better if there is a way to get the p values I want by changing the parameters of the fit function.

Comment: `statsmodels` doesn't do that out of the box, but since it's open source you're welcome to contribute such feature

Answer (score 0):

The p-value corresponds to the probability of observing this value of `a` under the null hypothesis (which is typically 0 as this is the case when there is no effect of the covariate `x` on the outcome `y`).

This is under the assumptions of linear regression which among other things state that `a` follows a normal distribution. Therefore, if you really want to change your null hypothesis to be `a=2` then just transform `a` such that `a_ = a - 2` now when `a=2`, `a_` will be 0 as per the usual assumption.

So you can achieve this by solving for `y+2x = a_*x + b` and you will have a p-value for the probability that `a=2` would occur by chance. As I said though this is a fairly unusual test...

Comment: Thanks, so there is no way that I can get the p values I want by changing the parameters of the fit function?

Comment: You could always just calculate the p-value yourself? You are given the mean estimate for a and the sample standard deviation. You could use the values from the OLS output to construct your own t-statistic?